# Blanket Delegate Access in Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-2010, exchange

I'm writing an integration piece for an application that needs to be able to connect to our exchange server and read/create/update/delete anything on any user's behalf, just as if it were that user. So, essentially a delegate. Is there a way to set up an account that is automatically a delegate for all accounts on the server?

Thank you,
Tedderz

Comment: If you look at the documentation for Blackberry Enterprise Server and Exchange 2010 integration it has a bunch of information on setting up the BES service account to have that level of access, so you could translate that across to your own application's needs pretty easily I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Exchange Services group in Active Directory that is created with the installation of Exchange 2010 has full access permissions on all mailboxes by default.